# Programatically read value of runtime setting

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which creates a huge dictionary. In order for it to work, I enabled the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` in my `web.config` under the `<configuration>` section:

```
    <runtime>
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
```

This works in my local environment, but when deploying it in another environment which is not under my control, they get `System.OutOfMemoryException: Array dimension exceeds supported range`, which is the same error I had before adding that configuration.

**What I need**

I'd like to check on runtime if `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` was correctly read from the `web.config`.

**Why I need it**

I would like to make the application log if the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` mode is on, in order to verify that it is working in the other environment.

I think that maybe some configuration on their IIS server might be overriding or forcing the ignore of the setting in the app's web.config.

Comment: You'd also need to determine if the system is running a 32bit OS rather than 64bit.

Comment: I think, you probably compiling under AnyCPU and they running your app in x32. Also, consider using SortedDictionary instead. It will cost you much lower in memory and  probably a little bit slower in speed for such a big collection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm pretty sure I'm compiling it in x64 and not in AnyCPU. So that issue is discarded

Answer (score 2):

After 3 years still unanswered, and I had the same question. Took me 2 days, and finally I got it working:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Is64BitProcess :" + Environment.Is64BitProcess); // this works on 64 bit processes only

        // make sure that the flag is set, for using objects > 2GB:
        Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationSection oRuntimeSection = configFile.GetSection("runtime");
        string str = oRuntimeSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
        if (str == null)
        {
            oRuntimeSection.SectionInformation.SetRawXml("<runtime><gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled = \"true\" /></runtime>");
            configFile.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Better late than never! Would you change the comments to english, please?